# Angular 2 Routing run in new tab

Tags: angular, typescript

I am working with a asp.net core application with angular2 and my routing is working fine.

```xml
<a target="target" routerLink="/page1" routerLinkActive="active">Associates</a> 
<a routerLink="/page2" routerLinkActive="active">Account managers</a>
```

I want to open every page link (routerLink) in a new tab. Is it possible that every link is open in a new tab, without refreshing the page?

I have tried to replace `routerLink="/Page2"` by `target="target" href="/associates"` but the page refreshes all the reference.

Comment: Real question is why would you want to do this?

Comment: its project requirement , tell me is it possible or not ..

Comment: Did you tried target="_blank" href="/page2"? But seem it is impossible If you want to open a page in new tab and still want to make a link as active.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Try this please, `<a target="_blank" routerLink="/Page2">`

---

**Update1:** Custom directives to the rescue! Full code is here: https://github.com/pokearound/angular2-olnw

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, Input, Inject } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({ selector: '[olinw007]' })
export class OpenLinkInNewWindowDirective {
    //@Input('olinwLink') link: string; //intro a new attribute, if independent from routerLink
    @Input('routerLink') link: string;
    constructor(private el: ElementRef, @Inject(Window) private win:Window) {
    }
    @HostListener('mousedown') onMouseEnter() {
        this.win.open(this.link || 'main/default');
    }
}
```

Notice, Window is provided and OpenLinkInNewWindowDirective declared below:

```
import { AppAboutComponent } from './app.about.component';
import { AppDefaultComponent } from './app.default.component';
import { PageNotFoundComponent } from './app.pnf.component';
import { OpenLinkInNewWindowDirective } from './olinw.directive';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';


const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', component: AppDefaultComponent },
  { path: 'home', component: AppComponent },
  { path: 'about', component: AppAboutComponent },
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent, AppAboutComponent, AppDefaultComponent, PageNotFoundComponent, OpenLinkInNewWindowDirective
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
  ],
  providers: [{ provide: Window, useValue: window }],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

First link opens in new Window, second one will **not**:

```
<h1>
    {{title}}
    <ul>
        <li><a routerLink="/main/home" routerLinkActive="active" olinw007> OLNW</a></li>
        <li><a routerLink="/main/home" routerLinkActive="active"> OLNW - NOT</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div style="background-color:#eee;">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
</h1>
```

Tada! ..and you are welcome =)

**Update2:** As of v2.4.10 `<a target="_blank" routerLink="/Page2">` works

Comment: it refresh the page

Comment: Doesn't this just recreate what an href would do in the first place, while overloading the [routerLink] attribute?

Comment: @nikolasleblanc I'm afraid that would be true, but, only if `a href` and `this.win.open` are same.

Comment: I don't get it. It's a new window. It's a new angular bootstrap. Just use a link.

Comment: @nikolasleblanc I'm not sure about current release, previously when we used `<a routerLink='..' target='_blank'>`, it wouldn't open a new tab/window - instead just refresh the current tab/window.

Comment: <a target="_blank" routerLink="/Page2"> worked for me, thanks!

Comment: Yes by defining target="_blank" routerLink="/page1"> definitely works but the problem is, the old page will be blank and will render the page again if the new tab finish rendering. Does anyone have the same problem as me?

Answer (score 24):

Late to this one, but I just discovered an alternative way of doing it:

On your template,

```
<a (click)="navigateAssociates()">Associates</a>
```

And on your component.ts, you can use `serializeUrl` to convert the route into a string, which can be used with `window.open()`

```
navigateAssociates() {
  const url = this.router.serializeUrl(
    this.router.createUrlTree(['/page1'])
  );

  window.open(url, '_blank');
}
```

Comment: One of the disadvantages with this solution is not being able to use CTRL + CLICK. A real UX lack

Answer (score 18):

This seems a little confused.

Opening your application in another window or tab will require your entire application to be re-bootstrapped, and then for your router to... pick up that url, convert it into a route, and load the appropriate component.

This is exactly what will happen if you just use a link instead. In fact, that's all that's happening.

The point of the router is to swap components in and out of your router-outlet, which is something that's been bootstrapped and exists within the confines of your running application and isn't shared across multiple windows.

Comment: Sometimes you actually need such a thing

Comment: @MathijsSegers Exactly, like when you want to open the same route with a different parameter. You will need to reload the page

Comment: in my case there is a list of products page. each product has 'Edit' button. users who use these products usually edit 3-4 of them in one session so it's easier for them to batch open 4 new tabs and edit them than go sequentially and edit one by one.

Answer (score 16):

This directive works as a **[routerLink]** replacement. All you have to do is to replace your **[routerLink]** usages with **[link]**. It works with **ctrl+click**, **cmd+click**, **middle click**.

```
import {Directive, HostListener, Input} from '@angular/core'
import {Router} from '@angular/router'
import _ from 'lodash'
import qs from 'qs'

@Directive({
  selector: '[link]'
})
export class LinkDirective {
  @Input() link: string

  @HostListener('click', ['$event'])
  onClick($event) {
    // ctrl+click, cmd+click
    if ($event.ctrlKey || $event.metaKey) {
      $event.preventDefault()
      $event.stopPropagation()
      window.open(this.getUrl(this.link), '_blank')
    } else {
      this.router.navigate(this.getLink(this.link))
    }
  }

  @HostListener('mouseup', ['$event'])
  onMouseUp($event) {
    // middleclick
    if ($event.which == 2) {

      $event.preventDefault()
      $event.stopPropagation()
      window.open(this.getUrl(this.link), '_blank')
    }
  }

  constructor(private router: Router) {}

  private getLink(link): any[] {
    if ( ! _.isArray(link)) {
      link = [link]
    }

    return link
  }

  private getUrl(link): string {
    let url = ''

    if (_.isArray(link)) {
      url = link[0]

      if (link[1]) {
        url += '?' + qs.stringify(link[1])
      }
    } else {
      url = link
    }

    return url
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In my use case, I wanted to asynchronously retrieve a url, *and then* follow that url to an external resource in a new window. A directive seemed overkill because I don't need reusability, so I simply did:

```
<button (click)="navigateToResource()">Navigate</button>
```

And in my component.ts

```
navigateToResource(): void {
  this.service.getUrl((result: any) => window.open(result.url));
}
```

### Note:

Routing to a link indirectly like this will likely trigger the browser's popup blocker.

Comment: How to avoid the popup blocker

Comment: @Debadatta You have to select 'allow popups for this site'. There is no way to automatically disable popups for everyone who visits your site without their consent.

Comment: Thanks @Keenan , when I debugged the problem was somewhere else, thanks for the information.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to support Ctrl+Click or Cmd+Click this works on both Mac and Windows

```html
<div (click)="clickMethod($event)">Text</div>
```

The code now checks the event to see if either the ctrl or cmd key was pressed at the same time as the click

```js
clickMethod($event: MouseEvent): Promise<boolean> {
  if ($event.ctrlKey || $event.metaKey) {
    const url = this.router.serializeUrl(
      this.router.createUrlTree(['main', 'page1'])
    );
    window.open(url, '_blank');
  } else {
    return this.router.navigate(['main', 'page1']);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

little too late but just in case someone will need it - you can also use [location.prepareExternalUrl](https://angular.io/api/common/Location#prepareExternalUrl) for this:

```
 if (event.ctrlKey) {
  const url = this.location.prepareExternalUrl(`/places/${place.id}`)
  window.open(url, '_blank');
} else {
  this.router.navigate(`/places/${place.id}`)
}
```