# Angular 4 Open a New tab with same html template binding

Tags: html, angular, typescript

Is it possible if i have a button that when it clicked, it will open a new tab in browser that binds the same component and variables that declared before?.

```html
<label>Please Enter Your Email Below</label>
<input name="userEmail" type="text" class="form-control" required ngModel />
<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm" (click)="verifyEmail(emailVerification.value); isClicked=!isClicked">verify</button>

<!--is it possible to open/redirect this div in a new tab?-->
<div *ngIf="isClicked">
  <form>...</form>
</div>
<!--end of div-->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No,Even if you could, loading a new tab would is like reloading the whole bootstrap application which is no different than using URL link.

There is no reason to do what you are asking in Angular4.

also see comments from:[Angular 2 Routing run in new tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41355830/angular-2-routing-run-in-new-tab) to see similar explanation.