# Angular Open Component In New Tab

Tags: angular, pdf, printing

Is there a way to open an Angular component in a new tab? This is just for printing purposes, and the new tab won't have any functionality like buttons or functions that refer back to the Angular program. I literally just want to open a component in a new tab so that we can print things cleanly and easily.

I am open for any solutions, but the less 3rd party stuff the better.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 Routing run in new tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41355830/angular-2-routing-run-in-new-tab)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To expand Deepender's suggestion, Use `target` attribute set to `_blank` like this,

```
<a target="_blank" routerLink="/Router_Link_your_print_page">
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: how to pass data ?

Answer (score -1):

create that component and open its router link in new tab.