# Clarity Datagrid: open in new tab?

Tags: angular, datagrid, vmware-clarity

How do I get the routerLink to open in a new tab? I tried target="_blank" but it did not achieve anything.

My HTML:

```
<clr-datagrid (clrDgRefresh)="reloadItems($event)" [clrDgLoading]="loading">
...
    <clr-dg-row *ngFor="let item of response.results" [routerLink]="['../edit', item.id]">
        <clr-dg-cell>{{item.number}}</clr-dg-cell>
...
    </clr-dg-row>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular 2 Routing run in new tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41355830/angular-2-routing-run-in-new-tab)

Comment: If you want a new tab, you ought to use `href` instead of `routerLink`, but it is inadvisable to make the row itself clickable since it can impact the usability and accessibility of the datatgrid. It would be better to have a button inside of the row that opens a new tab.

Comment: @JeremyWilken href does not work for me (i.e. nothing happens)

Comment: You have to put it on an `<a>` link on a button inside of the row, href won't work on other elements.